# Why isn't Bluetooth LE working from the iOS Simulator to my device?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to figure out why my BTLE TI CC2540 keyfob is working with my iPad 3 but not with the iOS Simulator equipped with a new GBU521 IOGEAR adapter on Mountain Lion.

I've been able to successfully connect the iOS 5 Simulator Bluetooth in the general settings (it says on, now) to my BT adapter, and to be considered as 'powered on' in my proof of concept app.  I'm using a GBU521 IOGEAR adapter, which only worked after upgrading to Mountain Lion (tried Lion with some hack modifying some .kext files-- don't do that.  Upgrading to Mountain Lion was impossible until I reverted that .kext).  I then ran the Apple suggested nvram setting, rebooted, and it was able to recognize the BT adapter.

I'm able to communicate with my iPad 3 successfully (registering the button pushes, accelerometer, etc), but when I try to run it on the simulator, it just doesn't discover the device.  It's telling me the BT state is CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn, but then when I tell it to discover peripherals, it comes up with nothing.

How can I establish Bluetooth LE communication between the iOS Simulator and an LE-enabled iOS device?

Answer (score 1):

(modified from my answer in other iOS Simulator Bluetooth thread here: [Bluetooth Dongle and iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202916/bluetooth-dongle-and-ios-simulator/13293393))

Throw away the IOGEAR and pick up a Cirago BTA8000.

I'm not sure why you were able to turn Bluetooth on in the iOS Simulator (possibly related to your kext editing, which I tried too), but I suspect it's not actually on. I bought the IOGEAR you mention, in addition to the Cirago BTA8000, and the MediaLink 4.0 adapter. Turns out that anything based on the Broadcom chip won't work despite my MacBook having the exact same one built in, which means the MediaLink and IOGEAR don't work. My Cirago shipment just arrived this morning, and the Bluetooth slider in the iOS Simulator flicks to "ON" in less than a second.

If you want to experiment, I'd love to hear if other non-Broadcom chips work too.

Answer (score -1):

Does your keyfob didn't came with a dongle? I'm planning to buy one :S
Update: I've just found this(But probably you have arleady seen this, it explains why you are using a separate adapter): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html
Also the reviews on amazon of your adapter doesn't look very good. have you tried it with antoher device? [http://www.amazon.com/IOGEAR-Bluetooth-Micro-Adapter-GBU521/dp/B007GFX0PY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1344560021&sr=8-1&keywords=GBU521+IOGEAR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007GFX0PY)