# Bluetooth Dongle and iOS Simulator

Tags: bluetooth, ios-simulator

I have bought an IOGEAR GBU521 bluetooth dongle as per the instruction on Apple's technote:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html

I have also configured it as instructed and I'm trying to get the temperaturesensor demo to work but the Bluetooth under settings never seems to turn on (keeps spinning). Looking at the console, here is what I see:

2012-11-02 4:17:08.114 PM Preferences[862]: BTM: setting discoverable status enabled
2012-11-02 4:17:08.114 PM Preferences[862]: BTM: setting connectable enabled
2012-11-02 4:17:08.115 PM Preferences[862]: BTM: enabling device scanning
2012-11-02 4:17:08.115 PM Preferences[862]: BTM: failed to start scanning with error 111

Any thoughts? I've seen people ask about this but has anyone got this approach to work?

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw away the IOGEAR and pick up a Cirago BTA8000.

I bought the IOGEAR you mention, in addition to the Cirago BTA8000, and the MediaLink 4.0 adapter. Turns out that anything based on the Broadcom chip won't work despite my MacBook having the exact same one built in, which means the MediaLink and IOGEAR don't work. My Cirago shipment just arrived this morning, and the Bluetooth slider in the iOS Simulator flicks to "ON" in less than a second.

If you want to experiment, I'd love to hear if other non-Broadcom chips work too.

Comment: That seems to be the conclusion at this point. I opted for buying an iPod Touch with BT 4.0. I needed to get one anyways. Thanks though!

Comment: @blued Hey Cirago BTA800 will work as independent dongle..? i mean i want search device over bluetooth in iphone app and want to discover Cirago name in their list? is it possible..?

Answer (score 0):

I just bought a GBU521 from amazon to upgrade the BT in my MacBook8,3

I had the same problem of it not showing up.  Reading the same article you referenced ([TN2295](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2295/_index.html)) I did a `sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior="always"` which tells the system to ALWAYS switch to a bluetooth controller if one is plugged in.

The `default` option:

> when a new HCI is connected, the built-in driver only disconnects from the built in HCI and attaches to the external HCI if the new module is not an Apple module.

I presume that because the vendor IDs matched (`0xa5c`) that it was not switching over to the new dongle.  Setting it to `always` causes OSX to always switch to a new BT adapter.  This is confirmed by the following statement in [TN2295](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2295/_index.html):

> Open the System Information application to verify that the system Bluetooth driver is matched to **the built-in Bluetooth host controller** interface (HCI). For the Hardware->Bluetooth setting, verify that the **Vendor ID is "0x5AC"**.

Rebooting after the `nvram` update and I was able to re-pair all of my devices without incident.

HOWEVER this will **not work** for iOS BT LE development due to the following statement in [TN2295](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2295/_index.html):

> If the system Bluetooth controller is matched to the Bluetooth LE USB adapter, then the iOS simulator will not be able to use the external Bluetooth controller for Bluetooth LE services.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can mod the `Info.plist` inside the `BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport.kext` found here:

> /System/Library/Extensions/IOBluetoothFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport.kext/Contents/Info.plist...

Just copy another Broadcom dictionary and modify it or use the following additon to the `Info.plist`. You'll need to do this as an admin (i.e. `sudo nano` or `vi` this file after making a copy of the original).

```
    <key>Add an appropriate name here</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport</string>
        <key>IOClass</key>
        <string>BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport</string>
        <key>IOProviderClass</key>
        <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
        <key>idProduct</key>
        <integer>8680</integer>
        <key>idVendor</key>
        <integer>2652</integer>
    </dict>
```

May need to reboot after the edit. Did this on 2012 MacBook Pro, ran XCode, and it allowed access to the Bluetooth dongle in iOS Simulator!

I hope this helps!